# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: index)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate, predicate

I am developing a autocomplete text field and this happened

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:autocompleteTextField.text];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" CityCode[c] contains %@ OR Zone[c] contains %@ ",substring,substring];
filteredarr =[[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy];
```

Error occurs at line

> filteredarr =[[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
>   copy];

filteredarr is an array 
searcharray is an array which took json data

please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your substring is empty.

Comment: substring is not empty ... but while sending into an empty array , problem occured

Comment: Yes because you are trying to add nothing in the array, hence the error. You need to check if  `[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]` return something and only the `copy` that in `filteredarr`

Comment: `CityCode contains[c] %@ OR Zone contains[c] %@` instead? That seems to fix it, but I don't know why exaclty. What I guess, is that somehow, it's maybe using `subscript` on `CityCode` with `c` and why you get an "setObject:ForKey:" with nil.

Comment: Thanks @Larme . That worked . You are a life saver

Comment: I always use `contains` or `contains[c]`, meaning I put the `[c]` after `contains` (which is a key word on predicates), not on a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" CityCode[c] contains %@ OR Zone[c] contains %@ ",substring,substring];
```

You need to put the `[c]` (for case insensitive) after the reserved word `contains`, not on the `key`

=>

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CityCode contains[c] %@ OR Zone contains[c] %@ ",substring,substring];
```

For the error itself (message wasn't quite explicit), I guess that is why trying to subscript on `CityCode` and `Zone` with `c` key, get nil, and that's why you got a `setObject:forKey:` with nil error (you can't put a `nil` value on an object).

For habits, I like to put reserved predicate words in uppercase, it's easier to read if it's a reserved word and has an "action" => `CONTAINS[c]`, but that's just my tastes.